# Can I get my http back in the address bar in Firefox?

Tags: http, firefox

Since Firefox 7 (or 6?) they silently removed "http" from the address bar. Previously, when you clicked it, "http" showed up again, allowing to easily just change http into https.

So far, I found two ways to get it back, but isn't there a setting I can use to have it permanently in vision again, or at least when I click it?

- Way 1: copy selection and paste it again
- Way 2: type the whole scheme again in front of the address
- ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the mozillazine forum](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2325047):

> Type about:config in Location (address) bar filter for
>   `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` right-click or double-left-click and Toggle
>   this to false
>
> The http:// should then show up again.
>
> oh and setting the `browser.urlbar.formatting.enabled` preference as
>   false may be of interest also.

Comment: Those settings don't both hide-during-view and show-when-edit (Opera behavior), but I don't see other settings that can do this, so I guess it's either all or nothing here.

Answer (score 2):

With a recent update, the autocomplete changed so that if you make a request on http and then change the request to https (but leave everything else unchanged), it changes it back to http. Similar thing happens if you first make the request on https and then change to http.

At first I got around this by adding something random like "?0" at the end of the url, but I found out that disabling `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled` in the config also fixed the problem.

EDIT: As several people have pointed out, this is not really a *solution* as such. It just shows that it's new "awesome bar" features that have introduced the problem :) (the adding meaningless http arguments to the address bar *might* be a long term solution, if you don't have to do it too often).

Comment: Quite a drastic workaround as it kills quite some features, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: Indeed. The awesome bar is the best thing about Firefox (that about about:config), so I hope this will get fixed at some point. I would have submitted a bug report, but it seems a lot of work :P

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't want to disable the URL bar autocompletion. See http://superuser.com/q/503411/151741

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen to me any more... I guess it has been fixed at some point with a later update...