# When I enter an address with https, Firefox (sometimes) changes it to http

Tags: firefox, redirection, https, url

What I did:

1. I visited `https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Main_Page` (yes, there is a [dot after TLD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13309854/1591669))
2. I got an SSL error (because the cert isn't valid for the domain name with dot)
3. I visited `http://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Main_Page` (not `https`)
4. I opened a new tab and entered `https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Main_Page` again
5. *Now* Firefox transforms this URL and changes `https` to `http`

I don't think that it's a redirect initiated by the site, because:

- it *immediately* changes the URL after hitting enter, even before the connection to the site is established
- when I enter the URL in a different browser, it works

I noticed it with URLs that produced an SSL error. Maybe some kind of caching to prevent that users see SSL errors again? How could I deactivate this without disabling/cleaning the whole cache?

---

EDIT: [Svend Hansen seems to notice the same problem](https://superuser.com/a/450885/151741), but his fix was to disable the whole URL bar autocomplete.

Comment: Second tab retains https here (FF 16.0.2 on Windows).

Comment: @Karan: I found someone with the same problem (see EDIT in my question), and he described another step I also followed before, but I thought it would not be relevant here: visit the `http` variant, too (I added this step in the question; don't know if it would make a difference for you).

Comment: Yep, that extra step does it. Will have to see if this behaviour is even officially documented anywhere.